# How to use `select` library on Python for non-blocking keyboard input outside of console?

Tags: python, input, user-input

I am looking for non-blocking keyboard input in Python. The idea is to display an input text box during 5 seconds, and if no input has been received, it automatically passes to the next line. `input()` function always waits until the user inputs something to continue, so it's not a valid option.

I found this:

```
while True:
     # Check if there is input ready
     if select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0) == ([sys.stdin], [], []):
         input_str = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
         # Do something with the input
         print("Input received:", input_str)
     else:
         # Do something else if there is no input
         pass
```

Which works as intended (I would only need to change the condition of the `while` to add my timer), but only on console. I need it on a notebook, where if I try it it doesn't display any input box and just prints "Input received:", as if it was constantly receiving an empty string.

Is there a way to use this outside of console? Or maybe some other library?

Comment: By "notebook", do you mean a Jupyter notebook?  Have you looked at the `keyboard` module?

Comment: would probably need to try `asyncio` for non blocking...